# Confusion about openess in locally path connected spaces

Tags: algebraic-topology

> A space $X$ is locally path connected if and only path components
>   of open subsets are open.

What exactly does path components of open subsets are open mean?

Does the first part mean path components of the subset or the superset, and does the last open mean open in the subset or open in the superset?

Comment: To be open in $U$ means it is the intersection of $U$ with an open set in $X$, which then becomes open in $X$ being the intersection of two open sets in $X$. So when the path components of $U$ are open that means they are open in $X$ also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $U$ be an open subset of $X$.

The path components of $U$ are the equivalence classes of $U$
under the relation $u\sim v$ if there is a path in $U$ joining $u$ and $v$.

Note that a subset $A$ of $U$ is open in $U$ iff it is open in $X$.

Then $X$ is locally path connected if the path components of every open subset $U$ are open (in $X$ or in $U$).